# Code Snippet: remove "read" permissions for non-admins

Tags: marketing-cloud, permissions, content-builder

I'd like to create a code snippet that can only be viewed by admins on the account. The code snippet would contain sensitive key information for a tokenized parameter and only admins should have access to Read or Write.

It only seems possible to share/edit permissions at a business unit level. Has anyone found otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding it is not possible because salesforce has no special content permissions on individual files.

The only thing that i could think of would be moving those to shared content and restrict access to shared content to everyone but system administrators. (But i am not even sure on that one)